# How can I remove divider before actionbar menuItem which only have text on it?

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock

I want to remove short divider before ActionBar's `MenuItem` which has "withText" option in it.

I've tried many different theme setting with it, but failed.

Is there any solution to remove it?

This is my theme xml.

```
 <style name="my_actionbar" parent="@style/Widget.Sherlock.Light.ActionBar.Solid">
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/actionbar_bg</item>
    <item name="background">@drawable/actionbar_bg</item>
    <item name="android:actionBarDivider">@null</item>
    <item name="actionBarDivider">@null</item>
    <item name="android:showDividers">none</item>
    <item name="android:dividerVertical">@null</item>
    <item name="android:dividerPadding">0dp</item>
    <item name="android:divider">@null</item>
</style>
```

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The `android:actionBarDivider` attribute belongs to the theme, not to the action bar style. You can remove the divider like this:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.Sherlock">
    <item name="actionBarDivider">@null</item>
    <item name="android:actionBarDivider">@null</item>
</style>
```

Answer (score 1):

I've solve this problem by set android:listDivider attribute on main theme to some transparent drawble. But I don't know side effects by this setting.

main theme:

```
<style name="Theme_Main" parent="@style/Theme.Sherlock.Light">
    ....
    <item name="android:listDivider">@drawable/shape_blank</item>
</style>
```

shape_blank.xml

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:shape="line">
    <solid android:color="@android:color/transparent"/>
</shape>
```

Answer (score 0):

I removed divider line from tabbar with use of below magical lines.

```
  mTabHost.getTabWidget().setDividerDrawable(null);
```

OR

```
  mTabHost.getTabWidget().setDividerDrawable(R.Color.transperant);
```

Answer (score -1):

Use the below code in your fragment/Activity

```
getSupportActionBar().setElevation(0);
```