# How to remove pipe symbol | from action bar in android?

Tags: android, android-actionbar

In my android application i am displaying refresh,search,setting options in my actionbar . All are displaying fine but on tablet all are displaying with pipe symbol separator.

[image]

**Question -**

How to remove pipe symbol from actionbar?

Thanks in advance !

Comment: what do you mean by pipe symbol can you post the image

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The "pipe" symbol is known as the actionbar divider, and is linked to your application's theme. The following link answers your question: [How can I remove divider before actionbar menuItem which only have text on it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15743472/how-can-i-remove-divider-before-actionbar-menuitem-which-only-have-text-on-it)